# JTable won't show anything

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using IntelliIdea IDE and its build-in GUI-Designer, which is why there is some Code "missing". I tried to create my own DefaultTableModel Class, but nothing shows up. No errors or warnings. i am aware that there are plenty of other JTable issues on stackoverflow, but nothing helped. I call the createUIComponents method in the main-Method of another Class.

Frame:

```
public class SWOFrame {
private JTable      tbMainTable;
private JPanel      mainPanel;
private JButton     btnAdd;
private JTextField  tfWork;
private JTextField  tfHours;
private JScrollPane spTableScroller;

private String[][] testData = {{"hallo", "ianac"}, {"sssfs", "faffe"}};

public void createUIComponents() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SWOFrame");
    frame.setContentPane(new SWOFrame().mainPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    tbMainTable.setModel(new SWOTableModel(testData));

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

tableDataModel:

```
public class SWOTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    String[] columnNames = {"Work", "Hours"};

    SWOTableModel(Object[][] data) {
        for(String name : columnNames)
            addColumn(name);

        for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
            addRow(data[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This "frame.setContentPane(new SWOFrame().mainPanel);" looks suspicious to me...

Comment: it was autocreated, so i haven't even looked at it, stupid me. Removing "new SWOFrame()." solved the problem, thank you.

Comment: `I tried to create my own DefaultTableModel Class`- Why? The DefaultTableModel already has a constructor that accepts columnNames and data as parameters. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: i was just playing around to practise.

Answer (score 0):

To show table, you need to add table on `JFrame`. You missing to add table to `JFrame`. It is better to add `JTable` to `JScrollPane` and than add `JScrollPane` to JFrame. Add following code:

```
spTableScroller =new JScrollPane(tbMainTable);
frame.add(spTableScroller );
```

Comment: The GUI-Designer does that for me and stores the code in a separate file. Thats why i wrote, there is some code "missing".